# Using CSS to display XSTL table

Tags: css, xml, xslt

Okay so I've been having trouble with my first XML project, so I've turned to you guys. I'm trying to produce an address book using an XML file that contains the contacts data, that is then transformed in XSLT. Both the XML and XSLT files work correctly, but my problem begins when I try to implement my CSS file into the XSLT so I can format the page to match the rest of the website. Once the CSS is implemented, my table only shows the first row given in the XSLT and stops. Given below is the code for my three files, and the given response with the CSS file included.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="contactdata.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE addressbook [
<!ELEMENT addressbook (contact)>
<!ELEMENT contact (fname,lname,mi,staddress,city,state,zip,phone,email,twitter)>
<!ELEMENT fname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mi (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT staddress (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zip (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT twitter (#PCDATA)>
]>
<addressbook>
<contact>
<fname>Peyton</fname>
<lname>Manning</lname>
<mi>Z</mi>
<staddress>123 Go Vols</staddress>
<city>Denver</city>
<state>CO</state>
<zip>12345</zip>
<phone>1-800-youwish</phone>
<email>pmanning@broncos.com</email>
<twitter>peyton_manning</twitter>
</contact>

<contact>
<fname>Eric</fname>
<lname>Berry</lname>
<mi>P</mi>
<staddress>123 Arrowhead Stadium</staddress>
<city>Kansas City</city>
<state>MO</state>
<zip>34567</zip>
<phone>816-213-4452</phone>
<email>eberry@chiefs.com</email>
<twitter>eric_berry</twitter>
</contact>
</addressbook>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sitetemplate.css"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Initial</th>
                    <th>Street Address</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Zip</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Twitter</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contact">
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contact/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {font-family: Helvetica, Times, serif; color:white;}

.center {text-align:center;}

body {background-image:url('wallpaper.jpg'); font-family: Helvetica, Times, serif;}

hr {border: 0; width: 50%; color:white;}

table, th, td {border:10px white; background-color:blue; color:white;} 


a:link {color:#75B8FA; text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color:#75B8FA; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#75B8FA; text-decoration:none;}
a:active {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
```

And what is shown on the browser when trying to run: http://i144.photobucket.com/albums/r171/jmock89/giventable.png
(Sorry it's an outside link, I can't post images on StackOverflow until I have 10 rep.)

Comment: The transformation doesn't generate any link to a css file, so your CSS contained in your file isnt applied at all. The transformation must generate something like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourURL">`

Comment: Does this line of code not link the transformation and the CSS file? `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sitetemplate.css"?>` I thought that was enough to provide a link because if I go into my CSS file and change the values, say for table background color to green instead of blue, the change is represented when I open the XSLT file.

Comment: If this can be used to link to a CSS stylesheet, then this PI must be generated by the XSLT transformation -- the current transformation doesn't do that. **See the update to my answer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your CSS stylesheet is at:  `http://myUrl.com/myCSS.css`
then include the following in the transformation, immediately after `<html>`:**

```
        <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                href="http://myUrl.com/myCSS.css"/>
        </head>
```

**Alternatively, generate the styles inline**:

```
        <head>
          <style>
                    .text {font-family: Helvetica, Times, serif; color:white;}

                    .center {text-align:center;}

                    body {background-image:url('wallpaper.jpg'); font-family: Helvetica, Times, serif;}

                    hr {border: 0; width: 50%; color:white;}

                    table, th, td {border:10px white; background-color:blue; color:white;}


                    a:link {color:#75B8FA; text-decoration:none;}
                    a:visited {color:#75B8FA; text-decoration:none;}
                    a:hover {color:#75B8FA; text-decoration:none;}
                    a:active {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
          </style>
        </head>
```

**Yet another alternative**:

Generate the necessary processing instruction:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sitetemplate.css"?>
```

To do so, add this (immediately preceding `<html>`):

```
 <xsl:processing-instruction
 name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/css" href="sitetemplate.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>
```